# MD5 Post Data in sql query

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to do the following, but is giving an error, what would be the correct way of writing the statement;

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE $db_usercol= '".$_POST['myusername']"' and $db_passcol= '"(md5($_POST['mypassword']))"'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: What is the error? Also that code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I have already scaped the post data prior to the code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` is a good practice.

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM $tbl_name 
        WHERE $db_usercol= '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']) . 
          "' AND $db_passcol= '" . (md5($_POST['mypassword'])) . "'";
```

also, you forgot the concatenation symbol, `.`.

Comment: Thanks, i am learning alot, i had already escaped the post data prior to the sql syntax

Comment: escaping string as `$_POST['myusername'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']);` is not such a good practice. ;)

Comment: Whats the better way of doing it, I need all the advise possible, only 10 days since i started PHP

Comment: Shall we escape the password also?

Comment: You can chose to do so, but it wouldn't matter as you are encrypting the string too. Encryption using `md5` returns the string as plain alpha-numeric string.